# How to pass innerHTML content to th:field in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am creating a Spring Boot e-commerce website, and I have a `span` tag containing the total price so far in cart, and update with JavaScript behind the scenes:

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${chargeRequest}">
    <span class="total">
        Total: <span class="total-price">$0</span>
    </span>
</form>
```

and I pass a model attribute `model.addAttribute("chargeRequest", new ChargeRequest());` to this page, and ChargeRequest class is defined as:

```
public class ChargeRequest {
    private int amount;

    // constructor, setter/getter
    // ...
}
```

The question is: how can update `amount` in `chargeRequest`, and pass it back to the controller using Thymeleaf?

`th:field` is only valid for `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, I cannot directly put it to `<span>` tag

I have tried to pass 2 attributes:

```java
model.addAttribute("amount", new String("$0"));
model.addAttribute("chargeRequest", new ChargeRequest());
```

```
<span class="total">
    Total: <span class="total-price" th:text="${amount}">$0</span>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${amount}, id="amount", name="amount">
</span>
```

But I don't know how to update `${amount}` such that `amount` in `chargeReqeust` can be updated automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately for you, you won't be able to do that with a simple controller.  You will need a @ControllerAdvice that will serve as a global controller to be able to update the cart whenever someone adds a product into their cart or remove products from their cart.

In other word, you need a **GLOBAL CONTROLLER**. This global controller should check the **SESSION** attribute to allow you to change the amount of total cart and update it every time a change occurs. For example, check this out below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalCartController{
    @Autowired
    private HttpSession session;
    @ModelAttribute("cartModel")
    public CartModel getCartTotal(){
        if(session.getAttribute("cart")==null){
           //Here you create cart attribute for the session 
           // then
           session.setAttribute("cartModel", cartObjectWithUpdatedTotal);
     }
     return (CartObjectWithUpdatedTotal) session.getAttribute("cartModel");
```

}

Note that global controller will be always checked at every time at all routes and don't require a routing, this allows you to use the HttpSession autowired class which allows you to

> identify a user across more than one-page request or visit a Web site and to store information about that user.

Cheers